# Cassandra: Exception Connecting to 127.0.0.1/9160. Reason: Connection refused?

Tags: centos, vps, godaddy, cassandra

I have installed the **Cassandra 1.2.9** into my **vps server** which is having **CentOs**. I have Installed it successfully. when i run the **sh cassandra-cli**, i got the error message

```
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:183)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.open(TFramedTransport.java:81)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliMain.connect(CliMain.java:73)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliMain.main(CliMain.java:249)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:178)
```

`Exception Connecting to 127.0.0.1/9160. Reason: Connection refused?`.

I have checked the **jps** command and try to **kill jps** process. `ex: kill 9557.` Unfortunately again i got the error message likewise, `-bash: kill :9557 no such process`.

Please, advice me...

Comment: `Connection refused` generally means nothing is listening on the relevant port. Did you start the server process ?

Comment: In this version (Cassandra 1.2.9), there is no option to start the cassandra service. i have searched the bin folder too.

Answer (score 0):

try `ps aux | grep cassandra` to see if cassandra is running, for debugging this issue try running Cassandra in forground, in ubuntu I just do `cassandra -f` to start it in foreground and if there is any issue in cassandra config etc it will tell you here, if it starts fine then open another terminal and try to connect again, I think Cassandra is not running in your case that is why you are getting a connection refused.

Answer (score 0):

After getting this error ,  type `connect listen_address/9160;` on your console

where `listen address` is the address mentioned in your `conf/cassandra.yaml` file.